# Cant seem to get android-studio and flutter to work correctly on macos

Tags: flutter, android-studio, macos-monterey

I attempt to get flutter working on my Macbook pro. I used Home-brew to install everything from android-studio to flutter.

My problem is that when I try to launch a new flutter project using android-studio it asks me where the Flutter-SDK is. But I can't locate where it is installed.

I went with the Home-brew installation because it automatically adds flutter to your `$PATH`. I am able to run flutter doctor and after some trial and error now have no issues, except being unable to find where Home-brew installed the Flutter-SDK.

I've tried to use my terminal to locate the Flutter-SDK but my skills with a terminal are still pretty limited. I also attempted to dig through finder attempting to find where Home-brew installed it. I did learn that typically it installs to either `/usr/local/Cellar/` or it creates a symlink at `/usr/local/opt/`. However, when I am in those folders I do not see flutter anywhere there. There is a Dart-SDK but no Flutter-SDK.

I have considered installing Flutter via git but I think ultimately I'm just doubling in size what is already there.

Answer (score 0):

In your error case you still needed to download flutter-sdk in the official website https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos here and you would see 2 options, pick the one you need based on your MacBook pro processor.

[image]

After that you should unzip the flutter-sdk inside your project file.

[image]

Just paste it and your flutter should run now and don't forget to put it on your path using this command:

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```